# Error: "does not have storage.buckets.get access to default” when trying to connect to Google Cloud Console

Tags: sql, salesforce, google-cloud-console

I am trying to connect Google Cloud Console and Skyvia so I can run SQL queries using Salesforce data.

In Skyvia, I am getting error "does not have storage.buckets.get access to default” when trying to connect to Google.

I am not a developer or programmer, so a reply that would be understood by a newbie would be appreciated.

I have tried one thing, which doesn't seem to work.

Since this page
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles
says:
Role: roles/storage.legacyBucketReader
Has permission: storage.buckets.get

In my Google Console, in Permissions, I set "Storage Legacy Bucket Reader" to be "allUsers."  Maybe I am missing the default part?
https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser?project=flowing-tooling

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Open the Cloud Storage browser in the Google Cloud Platform Console, [click here](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser).

You will see a list showing all your buckets. If you don't see any bucket, create a new, you can follow [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets) to do that.

Then, copy the name of your bucket (it's something like: *your-bucket-name*.appspot.com ).
Finally, replace **default** for your bucket name :D